# How can I calculate the difference between two events in one measure?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-desktop

I'm new to BigQuery and wondering if there is some way to calculate the difference between `session_start` and `app_open` grouped by `user_pseudo_id`?

I need it to know the average time of app loading.

I have the next structure of the table:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AvdU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot` to flatten your table and `timestamp_diff` to calculated the time differences.

```
#Select avg(time_diff) as avg_time from
(
SELECT *, timestamp_diff(app_open,session_start,  second) as time_diff

from (
select 5 user_pseudo_id,  "session_start" event_name ,timestamp("2021-11-11 11:00:00") time  UNION ALL
select 5 ,  "app_open"  , timestamp("2021-11-11 11:11:11")
)
pivot ( min(time) For event_name in ("session_start","app_open") )
)
```

Comment: what if I already use the next query to have the structure of table I show on image in qustion :
`SELECT PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", event_date) as event_date,TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST(event_timestamp AS INT64)) AS date, event_name, TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST(event_previous_timestamp AS INT64)) AS date_prev,  user_pseudo_id,TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST(user_first_touch_timestamp AS INT64)) AS date_first_touch,platform
FROM analytics_265.events_20210805`
Can it works with your query somehow?

Comment: There are two dates now in your dataset. Please explain. Past your query inside the brackets of the `from ( .... )` in above query. And put in the pivot line the `min(date)`